# Is there a multivariate integer function f(x,y) that returns the number of factors of y in x with a closed form?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, functions, logarithms

I'm looking for a simple function in terms of the elementary and exponential functions that when passed an integer x and integer y, it returns the number of times that y can be divided from x such that the result is an integer. I believe that it is something along the lines of $\lfloor\log_y(x)\rfloor$, but I am not quite certain. I believe that such a function would be useful for my own interests. No particular usage. I'm just toying around with functions.

Comment: To make sure I understand $f$, for example $f(40, 2) = 3$, since $40 = 2^3 \cdot 5$?

Comment: I'm no expert, but I don't think it will really be doable without sums (so no "explicit" formula). For example, $\log_y(x)$ won't really work like you hope, because $\lfloor \log_y(x) \rfloor + 1$ counts the number of digits $x$ has, when written using base $y$. But using base 10 as an example, the number of digits a number $x$ has, and the largest power of $10$ dividing $x$ can be wildly divorced from one another; $f(1{,}562{,}000,\ 10) = 3$ and $f(1{,}562{,}001,\ 10) = 0$ but the logs of each are quite close.

Comment: In general, $f(x, y)$ for fixed $y$ is $0$ for large stretches of $x$ but spikes periodically; I just don't see any nice combination of elementary functions behaving like that.

Comment: What you are asking for, is a [valuation][1]. Which is to say, you are asking for the multiplicity, of the value y on a divisors multiset of x. not that it tells you anything without doing the math but you can notate this as:

$\mathbb f(x,y)=max(\{n:y^n\mid x\}) $

really you're asking for another way to do this.

  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_(algebra)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can propose the following approach. In order to simplify things suppose that $y\ne 0$. Remark that for integer $z$ and $t\ne 0$ the expression $1+\lfloor  \frac zt\rfloor-\lceil\frac zt\rceil$ equals $1$ if $t$ divides $z$ and equals $0$, otherwise. So we can put

$$f(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}  \left(1+\left \lfloor  \frac {x}{y^i}\right \rfloor-\left\lceil\frac x{y^i}\right \rceil\right)=
\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor \log_{|y|} |x|\rfloor }  \left(1+\left \lfloor  \frac x{y^i}\right \rfloor-\left\lceil\frac x{y^i}\right \rceil\right).$$

For natural $x$ and *prime* $y$ a similar expression follows from [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula),

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \left \lfloor  \frac {x}{y^i}\right \rfloor.$$

for the exponent of the largest power of $y$ that divides $x!$. Subtructing from  it the exponent of the largest power of $y$ that divides $(x-1)!$, we obtain

$$f(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left( \left\lfloor  \frac {x}{y^i}\right\rfloor-\left \lfloor  \frac {x-1}{y^i}\right\rfloor\right).$$

Answer (score 2):

I came up with this:

$$f(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor \log_y x +1 \rfloor } \left\lfloor \frac{\gcd(x,y^n)}{y^n}\right\rfloor .  $$

Not very elementary, I know.  But

$$\left\lfloor \frac{\gcd(x,y^n)}{y^n}\right\rfloor$$ is $0$ if $y^n$ doesn't divide $x$ and $1$ if it does.  So this sum counts $1$ for each power of $y$ that divides $x$.

Comment: @Typhon What is $n$ in your formula?  You can't use the answer to get the answer.

Comment: @Typhon  That's the point:  $n$ is the desired output of the function.  We don't know what $n$ is until we start running the sum.  We do know it will be less than $\lfloor \log_y x+1\rfloor$, but it might be a lot less.  Say $x=2^{3}3^{20}.$  With $y=2$, I mean.

Comment: @Typhon  At some point, the terms in my sum start being $0$.  We don't know when that is, but for the $n$ for which this happens is the output you want.

Comment: OK, try it for $y=2$ and $x= 2^3$ and then $x=2^33^{200}$;